# ¿bind_param() puede llevar un boolean?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una duda con `bind_param()`: sé que podés usar "s" para los tipos de datos `String`, "i" para los tipos `int`. ¿Y para los tipos de datos **booleanos**? ¿`bind_param` maneja otro tipo de datos o tengo que pasar mi `boolean` a un `int`?

Ejemplo: siendo "portada" un `boolean`.

```
$stmt = $this->conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO imagen(ruta,portada) VALUES (?,?);");
$stmt->bind_param("si",  $this->ruta, $this->portada);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partamos de la base de que en MySQL [no existen los booleanos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/other-vendor-data-types.html).

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d7YufPCeL8bFEVVYd1nwSg/1)</kbd>

Cuando uno crea un campo tipo `BOOL` o `BOOLEAN` este se termina convirtiendo en un `TINYINT(1)`, es decir, un número entero entre `0` y `1`.

Entonces la respuesta a la pregunta, "*¿bind_param() puede llevar un boolean?*", es si.

Para hacerlo no hace faltar convertir el valor de la variable, basta con indicar que se va a enviar un dato del tipo `i` y listo!